# Is it possible to pass background image as variable - vuejs + scss

Tags: css, vue.js, sass

I have some SCSS which works fine when making a CSS file

```css
.title {
  background-image:linear-gradient(
    to right bottom,
    rgba($color-primary-light, 0.6), $color-primary-dark), 
    url(../imgs/img.jpg);
}
```

What I would like to do is dynamically pass the image to the CSS when rendered, based from an image gotten when mounted

```html
<section class="title" :style="{ 'background-image': 'blog.coverImage' }">
```

Comment: You can pass it as an inline style background image.

Comment: What is the issue here? What is the `blog.coverImage` here? Could you please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue) to show the issue happening?

Comment: The codebox is pretty much the code above, but here you go. https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-pond-9jc1p?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue